# How to get from a variable's name to it's property in python

Tags: python-2.7, properties

I want to access the value of _height in the class Player as defined in its property with the string '_height', without string manipulation if possible.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, height):
        self._height = SyncVar(height)

    @property
    def height(self):
        return self._height.v

class SyncVar(object):
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v

 p = Player(5)
 var_name = '_height'
 print 'The value of _height is %s' + str(p.__dict__[var_name])
 # Wanted: The value of _height is 5
 # What happens: The value of _height is <Main.SyncVar object at 0x0000000002DF8198>
```

Comment: `<Main.SyncVar object at 0x0000000002DF8198>` **is** the value of the `_height` attribute.

Comment: But I want the value as defined in the property, similar to how if I were to write `print p.height` the value 5 would show.

Comment: Then you want to `getattr(p, "height")`, not `"_height"`